# blank space in the middle of the site

Tags: html, css, space

I'm making this site and there's a blank space between the image and the table I want to put, i tried to find if there was a code making that space but found nothing. where can be the problem??

Thanks!

```css
<style>
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

#nav {
 
 font-family:sans-serif;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 color: #383838;
 height: 27px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 9px;
 z-index: 999;
 

 /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFA600;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px ##FFA600;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #FFA600;
}

#nav a {
 
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 70px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 color: #383838;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 999;
}

#nav a:hover {
 color: #FCC772;
 z-index: 999;
 
} 

header{
 position: relative;
    width: 390px;
 top: 80px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
    z-index: 1;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#hd2{
 padding-top:90px;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom:15px;
}

.wbox {
 position: relative;
 top: -370px;
    opacity: 0.6;
 width:750px;
 height:280px;
 z-index: 1;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#textini {
 
 top: -570px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 margin:0 auto;
 z-index: 3;
}

#textini p{
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-top:0px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size: 28px;
 z-index: 3;
 color:#383838;
}

.s3{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position: relative;

}

.font_8{
 font-family:sans-serif;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}

footer {
    background-color:rgba(56, 56, 56, 1);
    clear:both;
    padding:30px;
 border-top: 0px solid rgba(146, 146, 146, 1);
 border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(146, 146, 146, 1);
}
</style>
</head>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 
 <title>Números & Vírgulas</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="nav" style="overflow:hidden">
<a href="index.html">INÍCIO</a>
<a href="index.html">ATUAÇÃO</a>
<a href="index.html">QUEM SOMOS</a>
<a href="index.html">CONTATOS</a>
</div>

<header>
  <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/2vjwxv5.png" style="width:100%;height:100%" alt="" />
</header>

<div id="hd2">
<img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/fn4n6q.png"; style="width:100%;height:424px"; alt="" />
</div>

<div class="wbox">
<img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2ypel9c.png" style="width:100%; height:100%" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="textini">
<p>Os Números constituem uma linguagem universal mas <br> uma Vírgula pode mudar tudo.</p>
<p style="margin-left:350px;font-size:15px">Por: Dr. Sérgio Rosa</p>
</div>

<table style="width:100%:">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</div>
</table>



<div style="width:330px; top:55px;" class="s3">
 <p style="line-height: 1.6em;" class="font_8"><span style="line-height:1.6em;">© 2013 Números & Vírgulas</span></p>
</div>
<!--
<div class="in" style="width:0 auto; padding-left:0px; right:300px;">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/n%C3%BAmeros-&-v%C3%ADrgulas---contabilidade-gest%C3%A3o-e-forma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-unipessoal-lda-?trk=top_nav_home">
<img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/jphpix.png" alt=" " style="width:24px;height:24px;margin:0 auto;float:right">
</a>
</div>
-->

<footer>
<br>
</footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `top: -570px;` something is going way wrong here

Comment: You really shouldn't be using positioning to layout **everything** on the page. I'd suggest you check out [**http://learnlayout.com/**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/92edpjdq/

Comment: or just simply learn how an absolute and relative positions interact with each other.  This markup is an absolute mess.

Comment: Do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/92edpjdq/1/?

Comment: can it be that that's causing the space??

Answer (score 0):

your space is taken up by `<div class='wbox'></div>` and `<div class='textini'></div>` they have a set height but you are positioning them by using negative `top` values.

Here is the site without the 2 elements [fixed](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJoeab)

So you are going to need to restructure your site.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know those texts would make all that fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `relative position to absolute` for `.wbox & #textini` : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92edpjdq/2/)**

**CSS:**

```
.wbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: -370px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    width:750px;
    height:280px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#textini {
    top: -570px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i did that and the values are now positive and the space is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue by updating your css with the below one

```css
#textini {
  top: -215px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wbox {
  position: relative;
  top: -370px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 750px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -370px;
}
```